# Expression for Normal reaction on bodies on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

A block kept on an inclined plane has normal reaction $= mg\cos(\theta )$. I was asked what will be the normal reaction on a car turning on a banked road and I had to add perpendicular-to-inclined-plane component of $\frac{mv^2}r$ (the centripetal force) to $mg\cos(\theta)$ to get the expression for $N$. Is this right and if so what makes the two cases different?

Comment: [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093)
are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific 
computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader 
audience. If you intend to modify your question, please read the links above carefully before editing.

Comment: @josephh I disagree with the intent of your canned comment. This is a conceptual question about why the normal force is different in these two scenarios. The OP is not asking for someone to work out a problem, nor are they asking for anyone to check their work.

Comment: A car on a banked curve needs only a horizontal acceleration. That would be similar to a block in a fixed position on an incline which has a horizontal acceleration.